# Fill a listbox with an array in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, listbox

Does anybody know how can i fill a `listbox` from an `array`? I only know the method with:

```
With Tabelle1.ListBox1
    .AddItem "Versuch"
End With
```

i want to make a `dynamic listbox` but still have no idea.

Comment: Just use the Listbox's `List` property, e.g., `Tabelle1.ListBox1.List = myArray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Listbox_Things()

'My Listbox is called "Listbox1" and it is located on "Sheet1"
'With the Listbox visible, F8 through this code

    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .List = Split("1,2,3", ",")
        .Clear
        .List = Array("One", "Two", "Three")
        .Clear
        .List = Array(1, 2, 3)
        .Clear

        Dim x() As Variant
        x = Array("One", "Two", "Three")

        .List = x
        .Clear
        .List = Application.GetCustomListContents(4)

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much! is it possible to see what ive selected in a multiselection? Ive choosen the array way because i think it is better to recognize which items are selected by a user with array-indexing